# Removing Padding From Body In Nuxt.js

Tags: javascript, html, css, nuxt.js

I thought of creating a website with Nuxt.js. I heard that its pretty cool and easy to use. I am having a little knowledge on vue.js but still cant find the solution to this problem:

How will I remove the padding of the body?

I know the default margin/padding is 8px.

I tried following:

1. Created app.html/idex.html at root and set the style.
2. Added style in pages/index.vue
3. Used both margin / padding with !important tag.

But still, cant find solution

Comment: What do you see in your browser devtools with the inspector? Do you have a [repro]?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `head()` function in your layout or your page.

```html
<script>
export default {
  head () {
    return {
      bodyAttrs: {
        class: 'reset-body'
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style>
.reset-body {
  margin: 0
}
</style>
```

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/nuxt-starter-pl9ywp?file=pages%2Findex.vue

Or, if you want to really set it globally via the `app.html` file it should also work (added to the Stackblitz)